# Can i use python image recognition with opencv in a ardiuno board without pc?

Tags: python, image-processing, arduino

I want to create a machine that can detect bottles from other objects, preferably with the capability to identify the type of bottle as well. I am considering using an Arduino Nano for this project, but I'm not sure if it's capable of doing so. Can the Arduino Nano handle this task and send the data? Also, can a microcontroller like Arduino Nano run Python code on its own?

I understand that using a PC would make this task easier, but I need the system to be standalone as I cannot afford pricey controllers. Any suggestions or guidance on how to achieve this with Arduino Nano would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely cannot run any kind of computer vision on an Arduino nano given the absolutely tiny resources available on it. Generally to do something like that on a small system you have two option, you either use a Raspberry Pi or similar single-board computer and likely also some kind of [PPU](https://coral.ai/products/accelerator). The second option is for the Arduino to handle capturing the image and preforming whatever logic you want based on if something is a bottle or not, but the recognition itself is preformed by a remote server that then sends a message back to the Arduino.

Another option is to not use a computer vision library that relies on ML like opencv and instead so something far simpler. You could do something like using an image to determine if a bottle is placed in front of the camera by detecting a change in color or brightness. This likely won't be able to tell the difference between a bottle and a rubber duck though. You can design your devise to limit the possibilities for what it can see (for example traffic lights often use cameras to detect waiting cars by seeing a change in the image in a certain pre-defined location, because that location is in an intersection it must be a car). While not nearly as accurate it is something you could conceivably run on an Arduino.

As for your second question, you can run python on an Arduino, you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/programming/arduino-and-python).